# Android USB Host not able to read and write data for Cp2102SerialDriver

Tags: java, android, serial-port, usb

I am working on Android host application where I need to read data from all attached device. Using usb to serial cable "Cp2102SerialDriver".

Here is the example link which I referring

http://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/

I am successfully able to display attached devices with vendor and product ID, here is the sample code

```
/** Simple container for a UsbDevice and its driver. */
private static class DeviceEntry {
    public UsbDevice device;
    public UsbSerialDriver driver;

    DeviceEntry(UsbDevice device, UsbSerialDriver driver) {
        this.device = device;
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}

final List<DeviceEntry> result = new ArrayList<DeviceEntry>();
            for (final UsbDevice device : mUsbManager.getDeviceList()
                    .values()) {

                final List<UsbSerialDriver> drivers = UsbSerialProber
                        .probeSingleDevice(mUsbManager, device);

                Log.d(TAG, "Found usb device: " + device);
                if (drivers.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "  - No UsbSerialDriver available.");
                    result.add(new DeviceEntry(device, null));
                } else {
                    for (UsbSerialDriver driver : drivers) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "  + " + driver);
                        result.add(new DeviceEntry(device, driver));
                    }
                }
```

I refer to the android host tutorial

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html

to communicate with the devices

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Pressed item " + position);
            if (position >= mEntries.size()) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Illegal position.");
                return;
            }

            final DeviceEntry entry = mEntries.get(position);


            if (entry.device != null) {

                IntentFilter intentfilter = new IntentFilter(
                        "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION");
                DeviceListActivity.this.registerReceiver(
                        mUsbReceiverPermission, intentfilter);

                Toast.makeText(DeviceListActivity.this,
                        " Registered for broadcast reciever ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendData();

            }


        }
    });


private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiverPermission = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                 if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                if (device != null) {
                    usbDeviceConnection = mUsbManager.openDevice(device);
                    cp2102SerialDriver = new Cp2102SerialDriver(device,
                            usbDeviceConnection);
                    try {
                        cp2102SerialDriver.open();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "cp2102SerialDriver is open successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                 } else {
                 Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);

                 }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

To write data I am using this code

```
String data = etText.getText().toString() + "/n";

                bytes = data.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                try {
                    cp2102SerialDriver.write(bytes, 3000);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

But while writing I am getting exception. Thanks in advance for any help here.

Comment: And what would that exception be?  Please edit the stacktrace of the exception from logcat into your post, so that we don't have to guess at what it might be.

Comment: No Chris, It is serial driver exception Thrown by interface CommonUsbSerialDriver

Comment: You still need to post the log of the exception if you want help.

Comment: Thanks for taking Interest here, I thought above code was enough to help. Now I have done it by myself that exception was occurring because  I was not checking USB manager have permission or not. I have added two lines if (!mUsbManager.hasPermission(entry.device)) {
      mUsbManager.requestPermission(entry.device,pendingIntent);
     }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I have done it by myself that exception was occurring because I was not checking USB manager have permission or not. I have added two lines on click on selected device list on above mentioned code.

```
if (!mUsbManager.hasPermission(entry.device)) { mUsbManager.requestPermission(entry.device,pendingIntent); }
```